# If element exists in a document

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's possible situation that my function is use out of date jquery element. For example when I use closer and callback:

```
    $("input").each(function () {
       var input = $(this);

       //here for example we remove input from DOM
       //and insert the new one input

       $.ajax(url, function(){
          fun(input)
       }
    });

function fun(input){
//do something
input.val('newValue')
}
```

QUESTIONS ARE: How can I be sure that reference on variable is still right. And if element has been reacreated how can I get new reference on new input (input doesnt have id and classes)?

**UPDATE1:** I made small update. we use old *input* reference in function *fun*. And *newValue* will not apply to new input coz current *input* is old value.

Comment: dont quite get the question. when you create a new input, simply set input = $(whateveryournewlyinputlookslike); ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether an element exists by checking the length of a jQuery object. For example:

```
if($(this).length < 1)
{
    // the element no longer exists in the DOM
}
```

However, you can use jQuery's [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to bind events to elements that exist now, or in the future, and perhaps that's a better approach than the one you're currently working with. For example:

```
$('body').on('click', 'input', function(e) {  
    // Place your click handler here.
});
```

[**This article**](http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/) might prove to be a worthwhile read for you.